# What is a good way to get desktop notifications on Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, notifications, desktop-application, desktop

I am creating a system that will scrape a given site or use RSS feed to generate notifications. What is a good way to display those notifications on a Mac desktop?

What is a common messaging system that could be used to send the notifications from the software to the desktop?

The system would probably run locally, and would be written in Ruby.

Comment: `Growl` has always succeeded in annoying me on my mac.

Comment: If you're targeting Mountain Lion, it has its own notification centre, which you should be able to use: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5362

Comment: AMQP-based messaging systems are great for this. Write a node to create the notifications and store them in the exchange. Write a node that lives on the desktop and receives notifications from a fan-out queue. Use a Growl-alike to display the notification to the user. But, without code your question is very likely to be closed because you didn't show enough effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-growl -> https://github.com/drbrain/ruby-growl

However you have to pay for Growl from the App Store, but it is nonetheless the best notification solution for OSX.

Comment: Growl is now part of Mac OS as part of the notification system. Talking to Growl doesn't take a gem. The shell can talk to it nicely, and Ruby can talk to the shell.